# How to pass the data to a component using Angular2

Tags: angular

> Error: Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string;
>   direvtives: typeof TabsPage[]; }'

is not assignable to parameter of type `Component`. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does not exist in type `Component`.
I am using Angular RC.3
Please help me.

Comment: It should be 'directives'. Is this a typo in the question or error in code?

Comment: You are using RC version and it's too old. update your apps (packages). lots of things is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, `direvtives` instead of `directives` (switched 'c' for 'v')